# How can a dead person forgive someone?

Tags: death, repentance-teshuvah, funeral-burial-levaya, forgiving-mechilah

At most burials that I have attended, I have noticed that the mourners, and frequently the rav and other friends ask forgiveness from the dead person for any sins they have caused them. Is it the occasion of the burial itself (i.e., death) that can offer forgiveness? If not, how does this work? How can a dead person forgive someone if he is dead?

Comment: http://www.vosizneias.com/99006/2012/01/16/kiryas-joel-ny-chasidic-history-belz-sends-delegation-to-graveside-of-satmar-rabbis-to-ask-forgiveness/

Comment: http://www.imamother.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=18725 scroll down to 1:37PM

Comment: Again, what makes you think that because someone is dead it automatically follows that they can no longer forgive? Is it that you believe that the soul cannot be aware of the request for forgiveness, or that even though it's aware it should  nevertheless not be allowed to forgive for some reason, or something else? What is the reasoning behind your assumption?

Comment: @Jay Usually forgiveness from someone is done verbally or in writing. How does a dead person accomplish this forgiveness in a way that the penitent would know that he was forgiven?

Comment: wouldn't the fact that one is supposed to ask the dead person for forgiveness indicate that either we assume it will be granted or that one is no longer accountable even if it's not granted (just as in the case of a living person who refuses to forgive)?

Comment: @DanF How does the deceased forgive and how the wrongdoer knows the deceased forgave are different questions.

Comment: How can a deceased person bless someone?

Comment: @Lee Talk about timing your question with my father's *yahrtzeit* having been yesterday! You asked an excellent question. However, I think we say *Zichrono Libracha* - may his **memory** be a blessing. This makes much sense, since we recall what the person did and how he behaved. I'm unaware that we directly ask the deceased to bless us.

Comment: @DanF May his memory be for a blessing! My point in asking the question was specifically that we *don't* ask the deceased for blessings: we ask the deceased to be a *Meliz Yosher* to Hashem on our behalf, or we ask for Hashem's blessing in the merit of the deceased. So too here: I propose that we are asking for Hashem's forgiveness.

Comment: @Lee You have an interesting idea. If you can back it with a source or two, I would love to see it as an answer. (There's very good chocolate babka, here for you. Too bad I can't email it.)

Answer (score 2):

it's not that the dead person forgives but rather that you do your best and God absolves you. As the Chovot Halevavot writes in the Gate of Repentance ch.9-10

> But for the sins towards G-d and man, it will be difficult to repent
>   for several reasons:
>
> 1. He may not be able to find the person he oppressed, or the person died or moved far away...
>
> What strategy should be adopted by one for whom repentance is
>   difficult? We will answer this question as follows
>
> Whatever category it belongs to, if the repentance is difficult due to
>   one of the factors we previously mentioned which cause repentance to
>   be difficult, then if the person takes on himself to fulfill the
>   requirements of repentance with all its conditions to the utmost
>   extent that is in his power and ability to do, then the Creator will
>   make his repentance easier, **and will pardon what is hidden from him
>   and not in his ability to do**, and will give him a nearer exit for deliverance from his sin and allow him to absolve himself in this way...
>
> If the oppressed died, he should return the money to his heirs. If he
>   hurt him physically or he spoke badly of him, he should confess at his
>   grave with a minyan of ten Jews and he will be forgiven for his sin,
>   as our sages on this matter said: "And if he had died, he should bring
>   ten persons and make them stand by his grave and say: I have sinned
>   against the L-ord, the G-d of Israel, and against this man, whom I
>   have hurt." (Yoma 87a).

Comment: @mevaqesh  how would you translate that וישים לו מוצא קרוב מחטאו וירחיב אמתלאתו בו

Comment: Whose translation is this?

Comment: @ray I don't know. At the minimum, I would use Rav Qafih's Hovot Halevavot which tends to be a little easier, and I would consult an English transliteration, e.g. Feldheim for the English.